# How can I change the photo size dynamically from the server?

Tags: java

I have a large number of photos on the Server. The question is I have to save the photo into every size I need. 
I find that many websites use the url such as http://www.abc.com/89-w100-h100.jpg to show the photo in any size. When I change w and h, I can get the photo in this size.
I just want to know how can I achieve this function.
ps: I can cut the photo into the given size. But I don't know how to show the photo on the browser.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to scale down a photo dynamically upon request.  You would need to devise a scheme of encoding the size in the URL (as you have shown in your question), then apply a scaling function to the original image, using the URL parameters as input.  This is assuming you are doing this on the server side.

Your question mentions something about showing it in the browser, so if that is what you mean, you can simply size the `<img>` element to whatever size you want and the browser will automatically scale the image.  This does require downloading the full-size image, however.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think they scale it based on request. Image Resize is a expensive operation. Usually big corps, upon uplaoding an image, they resize it then. ex: yahoo resize an image with 9 different sizes and they all have some sort of scheme like 89-w100-h100.jpg which they use to identify them.

On the other hand, best you can do to resize an image is to define height and width tags to img tag. However that might have some unwanted consequences.